# Google Map Marker not showing up after clear cache or on first page load, but appears on refresh

Tags: android, refresh, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer, clear-cache

I have developed googleMap with my markers in Android, but they only will be displayed after I refresh or do a filter and they would not be shown at the first run or after clear cache.

```
    protected void refreshMap()
{
    final boolean useClusters = NumericUtil.parseBool(getObjectModel("useClusters"));
    markerArray = new ArrayList();
    markersMap = new Hashtable();
    poiMarkersMap = new Hashtable();
    locationMapper = new ArrayList();
    IDictionary attachments = new Hashtable();

    safeInvokeSync(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            googleMap.clear();
            if (mClusterManager != null)
                mClusterManager.clearItems();
            //configOfflineMaps();
        }
    });
         safeInvokeAsync(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if (useClusters && valuesCount > 2)
                    {
                        if (mClusterManager == null)
                        {
                            mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(getContext(), googleMap);
                            mClusterManager.setRenderer(createMarkerRenderer());
                            googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
                        }

                        ClusterMarker clusterMarker = new ClusterMarker(position, marker.getTitle(), marker.getSnippet(), marker.getIcon(), entry);
                        mClusterManager.addItem(clusterMarker);
                        mClusterManager.cluster();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Marker newMarker = googleMap.addMarker(marker);
                        newMarker.setDraggable(checkPermissionsValue(Permissions.Update));
                        markersMap.put(newMarker.getId(), entry);
                        markerArray.add(newMarker);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

}

Comment: can you share some code

Comment: I put some parts of the code, I already use mClusterManager.cluster(); and I did  @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
              //  mClusterManager.cluster();

                marker.showInfoWindow();
            }

Comment: If I understand you, you need to call this method in onCreate();

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could add something to the UI from a background thread? And `refreshMap()` is being called after the map is ready?

Comment: Thank u all, it was about RefreshMap not being call in the first login.